# Formula for multiple if blank arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a formula for the following problem:

- If A and B are blank then C should be Blank.
- If A isn't blank but B is blank then C should be blank.
- If neither A or B are blank C should return the value of B

I have this part so far:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Mon!$C$14),(ISBLANK(Mon!D8))),"",(Mon!$C$14))
```

Comment: You don't cover the case of blank A and non-blank B.

Comment: In that case C would be blank as well. Its a case of if both A and B are blank C is blank and if only B is blank then c is blank, otherwise return value of B.

Comment: I don't know if this is a better way to put it but:   If A is blank then C is blank. If A has value but B is blank then C is blank. If both A and B have value then return the value of B in cell C.    Sorry I feel like  I am making this more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: It is not a better way to put it because it's exactly the same way you already have in the question (and it again misses the fourth case). In any case my answer stands.

Answer (score 1):

```
=if(isblank(B), "", if(isblank(A), "", B))
```

Alternatively:

```
=if(or(isblank(A), isblank(B)), "", B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A,B)=2,B,"")
```

So in your case:

```
=IF(COUNTA(Mon!C14,Mon!D8)=2,Mon!C14,"")
```